# Microsoft edge browser failing on windows 2019 dotnet sdk docker image

Tags: microsoft-edge, docker-for-windows, windows-server-2019

As part of a new testing requirement, need to install edge browser on Windows 2019 docker (tag is 4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019) jenkins agent for performing Selenium front end testing. Browser is being installed via choco and get the following errors. While Chrome installs perfectly, Firefox shows installing but takes a long time to complete, despite the folders created properly under C:\Program Files. Concern is mainly with Edge.

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)> choco install microsoft-edge -y
Chocolatey v1.3.1
Installing the following packages:
microsoft-edge
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading microsoft-edge 112.0.1722.48... 100%

microsoft-edge v112.0.1722.48 [Approved]
microsoft-edge package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
File appears to be downloaded already. Verifying with package checksum to determine if it needs to be redownloaded.
Hashes match.
Hashes match.
Installing microsoft-edge...
WARNING: Generic MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pe
nding reboot is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if
available. If not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\microsoft-edge_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for
 "Return Value 3" and look above that for the error.
ERROR: Running ["C:\Windows\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\microsoft-edg
e\112.0.1722.48\MicrosoftEdgeEnterpriseX64.msi" /qn /norestart /l*v "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolate
y\microsoft-edge.112.0.1722.48.MsiInstall.log" ] was not successful. Exit code was '1603'. Exit code indicates the following: Gen
eric MSI Error. This is a local environment error, not an issue with a package or the MSI itself - it could mean a pending reboot
 is necessary prior to install or something else (like the same version is already installed). Please see MSI log if available. I
f not, try again adding '--install-arguments="'/l*v c:\microsoft-edge_msi_install.log'"'. Then search the MSI Log for "Return Val
ue 3" and look above that for the error..
The install of microsoft-edge was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\microsoft-edge\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - microsoft-edge (exited 1603) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\microsoft-edge\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.

 See log for details.
```

Function used to install browsers

```
function install-Browsers(){
  echo "Download/Install Firefox and Google Chrome" 

  # Install packages
  $chocoPackages = "Firefox", "GoogleChrome","microsoft-edge"
    
  foreach ($package in $chocoPackages)
    {  
    Write-Host "Installing Package: $package" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    choco install -y $package --no-progress
  }
}
```

Ideally it should install the browsers sequentially and show that browser install has been successful. No issues in installing these browsers on the Windows 2019 server VMs.
We were able to install this successfully until last couple of months. Not sure why it is failing now.

Appreciate if you came across this and found a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you encountered Error 1603 when installing .msi packages. You can try to check whether:

1. Windows Installer is attempting to install an app that is already installed on your PC.
2. The folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is encrypted.
3. The drive that contains the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to is accessed as a substitute drive.
4. The SYSTEM account does not have Full Control permissions on the folder that you are trying to install the Windows Installer package to. You notice the error message because the Windows Installer service uses the SYSTEM account to install software.

Here's [the resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/application-management/msi-installation-error-1603#resolution) if the problem belongs to any of the above situations.

Comment: HI @kendrick-li thanks for the response, there is no prior installation of this browser since this is a brand new docker image that is not customized yet. However, looks like its an issue on the docker image. More details - https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/21495.

Have you encountered this issue on the 4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 sdk dotnet win image ?

Comment: Hi @ParamJ, unfortunately I haven't had the environment to reproduce this issue, but since it was easily reproduced on that GitHub post, I believe it should be a common issue of the 2019 image. If you'd like to report it, you can simply press `Alt+Shift+I` in the browser.